# Azure AD - Token auth to manage Azure Resources

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, adal

I have a Node.js app configured to authenticate with Azure AD, this part works. When trying to use the access token given by Azure AD, API calls to Azure's API states that they are invalid.

'Bearer authorization_uri="https://login.windows.net/", error="invalid_token", error_description="The access token is invalid.

If I use my id_token, I am at least able to validate it is a token, but it has the wrong audience/resource.

Comment: What API are you calling? What is the audience in the token?

Comment: management.azure.com, the audience is not the api. Trying to figure out how to get Azure AD/Token request to show the correct Audience.

Comment: Try using `https://management.core.windows.net/` as the resource when you request the access token.

Comment: adding that as the scope right?

Comment: Could you show the code you are using?

Comment: i was able to get the access token to work finally using the ADAL library.. now how do i convert that access token to authenticate with ms-restazure or the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

> 'Bearer authorization_uri="https://login.windows.net/", error="invalid_token", error_description="The access token is invalid.

According to your error information, I assume that the resource for the token is invalid,

As @junnas mentioned that you could try to using https://management.core.windows.net/ as the resource when you request the access token.

Or please add the demo code to get the access token.

> i was able to get the access token to work finally using the ADAL library.. now how do i convert that access token to authenticate with ms-restazure or the SDK?

We could get the demo code from [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/tree/master/runtime/ms-rest-azure). The following is the snippet from the document.

Login with service principal name and secret

```
var msrestAzure = require('ms-rest-azure');
var someAzureServiceClient = require('azure-arm-someService');
 msRestAzure.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(clientId, secret, domain, function(err, credentials) {
   if (err) return console.log(err);
   var client = new someAzureServiceClient(credentials, 'your-subscriptionId');
   client.someOperationGroup.method(param1, param2, function(err, result) {
     if (err) retutrn console.log(err);
     return console.log(result);
   });
 });
```